# Why can't I buy a house in Morthal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I've played *Skyrim* five times now, and this is my sixth playthrough. This is the first time I've joined the Stormcloaks instead of the Empire. I heard that it could affect who sells you land, so I thought that was worth mentioning.

Anyway, I've become a Thane and talked to the Jarl's husband, whom I thought I was supposed to talk to, but the option doesn't appear for me to buy land. Why? Can I do this?

Comment: Did you talk to him at business hours (8 am to 8 pm)?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, depending on which side you joined the war, the place you'll buy will change, but not your ability to do so, as [this article on Elderscrolls wikia points out](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Houses_(Skyrim)).

I assume you're trying to buy the land to build "Windstad Manor". For future reference, I'll describe everything you need to do to get it.

**Step 1 : complete the side quest**

In order to be able to purchase it, you need to complete the side quest called "Laid to Rest", described in [this wikia article](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Laid_to_Rest).

**Step 2 : talk to the steward**

Then, you have to talk to the steward, between working hours (8am to 8pm). A player on Gamefaqs said "he would go at noon, just to be safe", in [his answer to that question, here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/346398-how-to-buy-the-property-in-morthal).

You will finally be able to begin your construction.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in my game, and none of the solutions in this forum or any other forums worked for me. I found a solution that did work, however, so I wanted to post it here in case the OP or anyone else in the future like me needs it.

What I think is happening is that if you side with the Stormcloaks and capture Morthal, or give Morthal to the Stormcloaks in the "Season Unending" main quest, the game still thinks that Aslfur is the steward, but he won't talk to you since he is in Solitude and no longer is the steward of Morthal.

The way I got around this was with these two commands below. **MAKE SURE YOU COMPLETE ALL NORMALLY REQUIRED PREREQUISITES FOR EACH HOLD BEFORE USING THESE COMMANDS TO ENSURE THAT YOU DONT BREAK YOUR GAME FURTHER!**

This command will give you the quest to go talk to "the steward of Morthal," which, like I said, will probably take you to Aslfur instead of Pactur. If he talks to you, great, but if not, use the command below this one to give yourself the property outright.

```
setstage BYOHHouseHjaalmarch 30
```

This command will skip having to talk to a steward, and will just take the 5000 gold, give you the land charter, map marker, and quest to go visit your new property in whichever hold you use it in.

```
setstage BYOHHouseHjaalmarch 100
```

Keep in mind that this will work for all three Hearthfire DLC properties, not just the Windstad Manor. These are all of the commands for each of the holds.

**Morthal**

```
setstage BYOHHouseHjaalmarch "30 or 100"
```

**Falkreath**

```
setstage BYOHHouseFalkreath "30 or 100"
```

**Dawnstar**

```
setstage BYOHHousePale "30 or 100"
```

I hope this helps anyone else who may have this same or a similar issue! Happy Skyriming and happy modding! :)

Answer (score -1):

The information in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302033/) is INCORRECT. That is how the game is supposed to work but **it does not** which is why the OP posted here. There is apparently a bug if you side with Stormcloaks in the civil war then the new steward is Pactur who **will not** sell you land. I am not aware of any workaround.

Comment: It is not incorrect, but *might* not work because of a bug.